# Is the Orthodox canon right?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, canon, protestant-bible, catholic-bible

I am considering becoming an Orthodox Christian but what is really stagnating me from joining the Orthodox Church is their canon: Orthodox Christians have a much larger canon than both Protestants and Roman Catholics (i.e. 3 Maccabees).

Does the Orthodox Church have the right canon and did any Christians hold to the same canon of the Orthodox Christians?

Comment: According to who? Obviously Eastern Orthodox Christians would say yes, and Protestants would say no. So what criteria would *you* use to determine it?

Comment: Church history, church fathers - things like that

Comment: Aside from some extremely progressive modern Christians, pretty much everyone believes history is on their side. So that's not a way to determine which canon is true.

Comment: I would not say the Orthodox canon is "much larger" than the Catholic one.

Answer (score 2):

One doesn't consider becoming something. Rather, one realizes that one *is* something and considers formalizing the situation.

If you are Orthodox, you will already know that they have the right canon.

Someone that says "I am [denomination], except I don't believe in some of the doctrines.", isn't [denomination].

But if someone wants to join a denomination for social, political, financial, etc. reasons, then it doesn't really matter whether they have the right canon.